# How to install git in PI snappy

Tags: ubuntu, git

My pi2 is installed with ubuntu-15.04-snappy-armhf-rpi2.img.gz, I want to install git in it but failed, here is info:

```
(RaspberryPi2)ubuntu@localhost:~$ sudo snappy install git
Installing git
git failed to install: snappy package not found
```

And because apt-get is not supported in ubuntu core, so I can not use it.

```
(RaspberryPi2)ubuntu@localhost:~$ sudo apt-get install git
Ubuntu Core does not use apt-get, see 'snappy --help'!
```

Comment: have you tried `git-core` instead of `git`?

Comment: git-core does not help :(

Answer (score 8):

If you want to install `git` on Ubuntu Core you'll need to install it using `apt`. You can install `classic` in order to get it.

```
snap install classic --edge --devmode
sudo classic
sudo apt update
sudo apt install git
```

Unfortunately, with this solution, anytime you want to run `git` you will need to first run `sudo classic`

[Source](https://developer.ubuntu.com/core/get-started/developer-setup#installing-and-using-developer-tools)

Answer (score 5):

I have not used Ubuntu Snappy, and that they decided to name the package manager `snappy` makes me cringe and want to throttle someone because of all the confusion that is bound to ensue in internet searches, etc.  This one is even more dunder-headed than the Raspberry Pi Foundation's choice of model names.

But it still did not take to long to find [this page](https://developer.ubuntu.com/en/snappy/tutorials/using-snappy/), which indicates that `snappy` (the package manager) does have a search function:

```
snappy search git
```

Should show you all the packages with 'git' in their name. I bet `snappy` even has a man page (which, thanks to the name, I could not find).  Try `man snappy` and see.  If not, there is the already recommended to you `snappy --help`.

Comment: Except that snappy search git prints: `Name Version Summary odroidc.longsleep 0.5 odroidc-community beagle.gumstix 0.1 beagle duovero.gumstix 0.1 duovero pepper.gumstix 0.1 pepper overo.gumstix 0.1 overo panda.gumstix 0.1 panda` which doesn't help much. At least not in installing git.

Comment: @JuhaAutero I didn't say you could install git via snappy.  I posted this answer because this is the first thing I would try, and in lieu of someone who actually uses Snappy and has actually installed git on it posting an answer, it is better than nothing.  If you do get this done, please do post an answer.  Unfortunately (or, for better sometimes and worse others), the way the site mechanisms work probably make it impossible for you to post comments until you have rep score of 50.  You can post a question, if you have one.

Comment: It is strange that git isn't in the repo, but OTOH, considering Snappy appears to be intended for *production* embedded systems with a *read-only environment,* it also makes a certain kind of sense.  You could install it from source, but at that point I would consider instead [switching to a more normative ubuntu](http://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/q/36378/5538), since this could be a clue that there will be an long chain of such missing fundamental *development* tools.